# Does injectivity change these proofs?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Here are the assertions I proved or disproved. 
$f: A \longrightarrow B$ where $C_1,C_2 \subseteq A$ and $D_1,D_2 \subseteq B$

$f(C_1\cap C_2) = f(C_1) \cap f(C_2)$ disproved

$f(C_1\cup C_2) = f(C_1) \cup f^(C_2)$ proved

$f^{-1}(D_1\cap D_2) = f^{-1}(D_1) \cap f^{-1}(D_2)$ proved

$f^{-1}(D_1\cup D_2) = f^{-1}(D_1) \cup f^{-1}(D_2)$ proved

Does injectivity change the result of any of these proofs? I know that injectivity shows that for any elements in the codomain x,y if x = y then f(x) = f(y). Would this change any of these results and what would the proof of that be?  I proved those equalities using the definitions of functions in set builder notation. Example, $f(C_1\cup C_2) = \{f(x) : x \in C_1\cup C_2\} = \{f(x) : x \in C_1\} \cup \{f(x) : x \in C_2\} = f(C_1)\cup f(C_2)$

Comment: Yes, the first is true if $f$ is 1-1.

Comment: How would I start a proof like that?

Comment: Certainly anything you proved shouldn't change when the function is suddenly known to be injective: You proved the last three for *all* functions, including injective ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first is true if $f$ is injective. It's clear that for any $f$, if $X\subseteq Y\subseteq A$ then $f(X)\subseteq f(Y)$. Thus 
$$f(C_1\cap C_2) \subseteq f(C_1)$$
and 
$$f(C_1\cap C_2) \subseteq f(C_2),$$
so 
$$f(C_1\cap C_2) \subseteq f(C_1)\cap f(C_2).$$ 
Thus if $f$ is injective, you only have to show that the reverse inclusion holds. Do this using elements: Suppose $y\in f(C_1)\cap f(C_2)$. Then there is $x_1\in C1$ with $y=f(x_1)$, and $x_2\in C2$ with $y = f(x_2)$. Because $f$ is injective, $x_1 = x_2\in C_1\cap C2$.

Comment: Ohhh, so then after that, it follows that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \in f(C_1 \cap C_2)$ and that completes that proof.

Comment: That's right — certainly then $f(x_i) \in f(C_1\cap C_2)$.